# Make Windows VirtualBox guest follow Mac host DNS resolution

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

I already have a custom domain name entry on my Mac's `/etc/hosts` file that I use for local testing. I'm able to connect from a browser using `http://dev.mysite.co:5000`.

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mysite.co
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I'm using one of the VirtualBox images that Microsoft provides to test my site in Edge. I'm running into CORS issues since I have to connect to my localhost using `http://10.0.2.2:5000`, so I'd like to reuse the domain settings from my `/etc/hosts`.

The node server on my localhost is listening on `0.0.0.0:5000`.

I ran this command which is supposed to get guest OSes to use the host's DNS, but I'm not able to load `http://dev.mysite.co:5000` inside my VM.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "MSEdge - Win10_preview" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Is this command still valid? Is there anything else I should be doing to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` file is not a part of DNS resolver. You could just copy your `/etc/hosts` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` but that won't work because from the point of VM `127.0.0.1` is VM's IP (loopback).

For that to work you should add to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` the following line:

```
 10.0.2.2       dev.mysite.co
```

which will resolve any `dev.mysite.co` request inside VM to your host's IP (which is i assume `10.0.2.2` - please check IP of VM adapter on your host's OS, via for example `ifconfig vboxnet0`)